# How to Make a Color Map for plt.imshow() be set to the same values on two different plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following. I have two plots:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(nonfour, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.abs(four), cmap='gray')
```

[image]

These two plots are created using the arrays nonfour and np.abs(four). When each plot is created, the color map is set using min and max values for each array.

What I would like to do is generate a cmap from **my first plot** and use that as the cmap for my second plot

(i.e. the colour map for the second plot will be based on the max and min values of my first plot).

Comment: `imshow` takes the keywords `vmin` and `vmax` to control the scale of the colormap.

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas Kühn noted, `imshow` takes the the keywords `vmin` and `vmax` to control the scale of the colormap. You can get the (automatically determined) values for your first plot using the `get_clim()` method:

```
# Create your first plot
img = plt.imshow(nonfour, cmap='gray')

# Extract vmin and vmax
vmin, vmax = img.get_clim()

# Create your second plot using these limits
plt.imshow(np.abs(four), cmap='gray', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `set_clim()` method:

```
img = plt.imshow(nonfour, cmap='gray')
img2 = plt.imshow(np.abs(four), cmap='gray')
img2.set_clim(img.get_clim())
```